# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\tester_folder'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, export-to-csv

I cant save my dataframe to csv on usb stick.

I already tried r"" strings,
`open(r"D:\tester_folder")`,
backslash and the opposite slash, and even with a non existent file "testfile.csv", but it wont work.

Is there a way to make this work?

```
df.to_csv(r"D:\Folder\testfile.csv")
```

EDIT:

It would work if the file exists before, but:

```
   if not os.path.exists(path):
       with open(path, 'w'): pass
```

also doesnt work.

Comment: You can try `df.to_csv(r"D:\\Folder\\testfile.csv")`.Also your are having tesster_folder and Folder as well .

Comment: most probably just a typo, what does `dir d:\tester_folder` say?

Comment: @Ricky nope still same error.

Comment: @Stef tried: print(dir("d:\tester_folder")) and it returned `['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', ...      'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']` but i have no idea what this is.

Comment: `dir` command should be typed into the terminal. If you are doing it via python use the `os.listdir(<path>)` method

Comment: Thanks guys for advice. In the end a small overseen typo and  `if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)`  did the job for me. Stay Healthy & Wealthy ;)